# how to get autoincrement ID of one table and insert in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table whose description is given below

```
Create Table

CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have another table

```
Create Table

CREATE TABLE `parent_question` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `qid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK8FEA83DBE860AF9` (`pid`),
  KEY `FK8FEA83DBF34C20F6` (`qid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8FEA83DBE860AF9` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `parent` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8FEA83DBF34C20F6` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have the right to insert one row in the question table.So when I add a new row then `id` will be generated (because it is auto_increment) and I want to store this id in the `qid` field `parent_question` table.

Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`last_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
insert into question values (...);
insert into parent_question values (..., last_insert_id(), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.I am using HQL.Will it be effective if some 100 users tries to insert at the same time and how last_insert_id () is related to question table.I have so many tables and each table has id field.so when I use last_insert_id  why it will fetch last id from question table

Comment: I did as you said but get error `Error Code : 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`surveytab`.`parent_question`, CONSTRAINT `FK8FEA83DBF34C20F6` FOREIGN KEY (`qid`) REFERENCES `question` (`id`))
`

Comment: A) if using raw sql, add parent first. If using hibernate, you don't need to worry because hibernate does it all for you, just create and `persist()` parent instance and create and persist the child. If you need the id for processing (bad design, but) then `flush` the session to force a database write, which will populate the ids.